# Java Serial Data Event Processing

Tags: java, events, event-handling, serial-port

The below code details an id read when a serial event happens,an id is generated every fews seconds when the device is powered on(Serial Event), and no serial data is received when it is powered off .problem is i need a url call to be sent once when the id is received and once when not visible(powered down).

I believe im close but cannot seem to get it right.I would be very grateful if someone could help with this and how to set flags and scheduler to achieve the above case and possibly explain where im going wrong.

```
int numberOfEmptyIds = 0;
int maxNumberOfAttempts = 5;
boolean urlSent = false;
long timeoutInMillis = 10000; // let's say 10000 millis, equivalent to 10 seconds
Timer timer = null;

public void connect(String portName) throws Exception {
    ...
    scheduleTimer();
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            while(in.read(buffer) > -1) {
                String asHexStr = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(buffer);
                if(asHexStr.contains("FB1")) {
                    scheduleTimer();
                    numberOfEmptyIds = 0;

                } else {
                    numberOfEmtyIds++;
                    if(numberOfEmptyIds == maxNumberOfAttempts && !urlSent) {
                        // send the url here
                    }
                }             
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           // Log the exception here
        }
    }
}

private void scheduleTimer() {
    timer = new Timer("Timeout");
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!urlSent) {
                // send the url here
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, timeoutInMillis);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is i need a url call to be sent once when the id is received
>   and once when not visible(powered down).

The second part is done by the timer, if no data arrives to the serial port then the scheduled task will sent the URL (if not sent yet). In my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647723/serial-data-event-listener-java) I forgot to cancel the timer when the task is re-scheduled :

```
private void scheduleTimer() {
    if(timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    timer = new Timer("Timeout");
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!urlSent) {
                // send the url here
            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, timeoutInMillis);
}
```

This way there would be a single scheduled task. From [Timer.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) javadoc:

> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. Does
>   not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists). Once a
>   timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully,
>   and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.
>
> Note that calling this method from within the run method of a timer
>   task that was invoked by this timer absolutely guarantees that the
>   ongoing task execution is the last task execution that will ever be
>   performed by this timer.

About the first part you can manage it with boolean flags just like `urlSent`. If you need to send the URL just a single time then you can have a flag for the URL sent by ID arriving and another flag for URL sent due no data (or empty ID's) received.

---

### Edit

Based on the flow-chart you've posted [here](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/rZlZ41SjhQ/) and shown below:

[Enter description here http://dl6.fileswap.com/storage_previews/02112014/54cd147697479d29c43c530b93d5fa83/52fe9168/aW1hZ2UvanBlZw%3D%3D/4cf59787af56f18847df6235cdc20816.jpg](http://dl6.fileswap.com/storage_previews/02112014/54cd147697479d29c43c530b93d5fa83/52fe9168/aW1hZ2UvanBlZw%3D%3D/4cf59787af56f18847df6235cdc20816.jpg)

You maybe can change your current approach using [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) method to check at a fixed rate of time a if the serial port stops reading the ID. As you need to send the ID received notification just once then you may set `urlSent` flag to `true` when this URL is efectively sent. Also I think you can get rid of check if the received data doesn't contain the expected ID. Something like this:

```
boolean urlSent = false;

long lastIdArrivalTime = 0;
long timeTolerance = 60000;

long timeoutInMillis = 300000; // 5 minutes
Timer timer = null;

public void connect(String portName) throws Exception {
    ...
    scheduleTimer();
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            while(in.read(buffer) > -1) {
                String asHexStr = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(buffer);
                if(asHexStr.contains("FB100000010F0801")) {
                    lastIdArrivalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if(!urlSent) {
                        // send the URL notifying the ID
                        urlSent = true; // next time url will not be sent
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           // Log the exception here
        }
    }
}

private void scheduleTimer() {
    timer = new Timer("Timeout");
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if((currentTime - lastIdArrivalTime) >= timeTolerance) {
                // sent the URL notifying the device is off
                urlSent = false; // this way the next ID arrival will be notified
            }
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, timeoutInMillis, timeoutInMillis);
}
```

Some notes:

- The timer is scheduled just once this time because it will execute the task every 5 minutes. If you need to shut down the connection don't forget to call [timer.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) method.
- The variable `lastIdArrivalTime` holds the last time in milliseconds when an ID arrives.
- The variable `timeTolerance` is a max time tolerance to assume the connection is down. As you've said the device sends the ID at a seconds fixed period, so if spent 1 minute since the last ID arrival then you can assume the connection is down (or device is off).

Some hints on your code available [here](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/uU1itGHq6w/):

- [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) implements [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface and is intended to be used using [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class which will create a separate thread to execute this task when the scheduled time comes, so don't use `TimerTask` in a new thread.
- Don't mess with
  [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
  unless you know exactly what are you doing. It's extremely easy make a
  mistake and mess the things up.

Comment: I probably should have said that this must be a continuous check and that if no serial data is received the event will fire(once) and loop back around to check either case again.the problem seems to be after the id is detected it does not check again for an id not being received.So basically as a use case when the tag id is in range of the serial reader url is called once ,and once tag id is out of range send a different url once.The problem seems to be after the id is received again.Very sorry for all this but thank you for your ongoing help.

Comment: @Maria88 you're welcome. Do you close the serial port connection when you send the URL either for ID received or missing? It's wierd because as is the code should keep listening to serial events. I've found some missing code for re-schedule the timer when URL for missing ID is sent (you must reset `urlSent` flag as well) and for resetting `maxNumberOfAttempts` counter when the URL is sent because of ID absent. Hope made myself clear but if didn't then I can edit and show you these changes. Hopefuly it's what you need.

Comment: Hi ive tried what i think is your explanation and cant seem to get it working,very sorry about this and thank you once again

Comment: Could you please add a flow-chart describing your use case? Sorry for asking that but maybe we can change the current approach to something more accurate. @Maria88

Comment: Hello,

I have setup a flow chart to describe what im trying to do with the serial event question i had ,i think it is an accurate description but at the very least you may get a better idea what im trying to accomplish.if you could look at it again for me that would be a great help.

flowchart available here:  http://www.fileswap.com/dl/rZlZ41SjhQ/


Thank you once again for your help.

Maria

Comment: I have setup a flow chart to describe what im trying to do with the serial event question i had ,i think it is an accurate description but at the very least you may get a better idea what im trying to accomplish.if you could look at it again for me that would be a great help. flowchart available here: fileswap.com/dl/rZlZ41SjhQ Thank you once again for your help. Maria

Comment: i think i believe i know what the problem is now ,The serial event only gets called when serial data is processed therefore the complete ,ethod cannot be executed if the device is not in range

Comment: @Maria88 you're right, if the device is not in range then serial data won't arrive and consequently your method won't be called. I was seeing your flow-chart and tinking about a little change in the approach using [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) method to keep notifying if no serial data arrives. If the problem still unsolved then I could post something.

Comment: I have tried something similar myself using the Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() but still cant seem to get it right ,if you could post something it would be a great help thank you,Maria

Comment: I have something currently but cant seem to get it right with just calling the url once for either the true or false case

Comment: My code currently which calls a url once if a serial event is not present but keeps calling the serial event if present(only need once)http://www.fileswap.com/dl/uU1itGHq6w/

Comment: Hi there! Please see my Edit. Hope it works this time :) @Maria88

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either ,seems like it never runs the second check for an id,my full code http://www.fileswap.com/dl/0M17CfDjP8/

Comment: I think `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(buffer)` is not doing what is supposed to do. Check the values of `asHexStr`. Note you're calling `scheduleTimer()` within `serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt)` method which is wrong because multiple tasks are being scheduled. This time you should schedule the timer just once, when you initialize the connection. On the other hand `timeTolerance = 6000` gives you a tolerance of 6 seconds which could work but seems too demanding. A wider tolerance (say 30 seconds) could be better, but you know the device so this desition is up to you. @Maria88

Comment: I have tried taking the scheduleTimer out and also checked the contents of asHexStr,the time tolerence was suitable as you sugguested i just turned it down for testing.Still cant seem to get this to run though

Comment: @Maria88 I'm sorry but I don't think I could help you with anything else. Without the ability of test your code there's nothing I can do to help you. Hope you figure this out and solve your problem :)

Comment: Hello I just wanted to offer my thanks for all your help ,I eventually figured this problem out and will update the code once its cleared up a bit.I continue to have a great deal of respect for this website and the help and experience that some people on here can offer,Thank you

Comment: @Maria88 you are welcome! I'm glad to help you and hope you can have your project working soon :D